# How to Show PDF file from local in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have angular web application and I need to show and print  PDF which located in my computer. How to show PDF file with print options ?
I want to show pdf located like
**C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xyz.pdf.**

```
<iframe
    src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0"
    frameBorder="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
></iframe>
```

I have tried iframe and other tools, but as I have to show from my local, it gives an error.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: You can’t load something directly from the filesystem, this would be a massive security issue. So Randy is right, you have to use a file input and then you can use the fileReader API to load it.

Comment: When user clicked button, in my server side , I am creating pdf file. So in angular side, I should show this pdf file and also it must be printable. Is there a way without user selection option ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer/) package.

Steps:

Import **PdfViewerModule** to your module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

class AppModule {}
```

After use this component in your tempalte:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
              [render-text]="true"
              style="display: block;"
  ></pdf-viewer>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**Render local PDF file**

In your html template add input:

```
<input (change)="onFileSelected()" type="file" id="file">
```

and then add onFileSelected method to your component:

```
onFileSelected() {
  let $img: any = document.querySelector('#file');

  if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.pdfSrc = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer($img.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to show pdf located like C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xyz.pdf.I want to upload from my local.

Comment: Actually I have tried what you posted but for the path like C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xyz.pdf it does not worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  Is there a way, doing it without input select option ?